# TFT pinout tracing

Tags: arduino, pinout, tft

I am total noob but curious when it comes to electronics, sorry if it's dumb or unachievable (shouldn't be).

Just bought ESP32, played with it and realized I need a display, found a 7-seg one with ET6226M, did a li'l research and used lib for TM1650, worked like a charm.

Then realized I need a better display, found 1.8" TFT 160x128, checked circuit of device for any driver IC to no avail, then I thought it might have a built-in one but I have no idea which pin is what.

LCD have no markings or numbers other than those found [here](https://www.rockbox.org/wiki/PackardBellVibe500Port) here (in the LCD section):

[Image reference 1](https://www.rockbox.org/wiki/pub/Main/PackardBellVibe500Port/Vibe500Lcd1.jpg)

[Image reference 2](https://www.rockbox.org/wiki/pub/Main/PackardBellVibe500Port/Vibe500Lcd2.jpg)

[Image reference 3](https://www.rockbox.org/wiki/pub/Main/PackardBellVibe500Port/Vibe500Lcd3.jpg)

Please help me figure out its pinout/diagram so I can connect it to my microcontroller.

It might possibly have ILI9163 driver because of the mention of 16 bits on the website but I am not sure, there are no other results on the internet.

I do have a multimeter handy, have incredible soldering skills, steady hands and am confident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a COG (chip on glass) LCD controller, then it is no way even possible to guess the controller. If you have the original product as well from where the LCDs were savaged, you can plan to use a logic bus analyser to monitor the waveforms. Even there it will be impossible to decode the signals into useful information. If the original circuit has the host MCU controlling the LCD, it might help.

Better off is to buy one with a datasheet.